# Error at line 5: PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, plsql

```
create or replace procedure NrCopii2 (NrNume varchar2)
as
  NrNume COPIL.nume%type;
begin
  select count(nume) from Copil
  dbms_output.put_line(NrNume);
end;
/
```

Answer (score 1):

There are some typoes need to be fixed :

- add `into NrNume` (just before `from`) and add `;` to the end of that
  statement presuming the data type of `nume` column is plain `number` or `integer`,
  otherwise you may replace `copil.nume%type` with `int` too
- either remove `NrNume` parameter of the procedure or local variable
  `NrNume` while replacing `NrCopii2 (NrNume varchar2)` with `NrCopii2 (NrNume out varchar2)`, those have same names, and one of them should
  be preferred to use

PS. don't forget to issue `set serveroutput on` whenever the procedure is invoked, in order to display the value returned for `NrNume`

As a result, the following code block might be used

```
SQL> SET SERVEROUTPUT ON
SQL> CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE NrCopii2 AS
  NrNume INT;
BEGIN
  SELECT COUNT(nume) INTO NrNume FROM Copil;
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(NrNume);
END;
/
```

Comment: you can pls show how its need to look the code because I'm pretty bad and i can't understand the second point pls if need i can show the data base

Answer (score 0):

You can make anonymous procedure as well.

```
DECLARE
  NrNume COPIL.nume%type;
BEGIN
  
  SELECT count(nume) INTO NrNume
  FROM Copil;
  
  dbms_output.put_line(NrNume);
END;
/
```

Comment: Can u make it in a procedure pls ?